# ParseError: syntax error, unexpected identifier "JobOpportunities"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I get the following error.

**Error**

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected identifier "JobOpportunities"

**JobOpportunitiesController**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $job_opportunities JobOpportunities::get();
    
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $allData = DataTables::of($job_opportunities)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editJobOpportunities">Edit</a>';
                $btn.= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="edit btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteJobOpportunities">Delete</a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);

        return $allData;
    }

    return view('System_admin.job_hiring_setup', compact('job_opportunities'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have:

```php
$job_opportunities JobOpportunities::get();
```

You are missing the `=`.

```php
$job_opportunities = JobOpportunities::get();
```

Comment: omy I didn't see that. thank you sir